# Dockerfile - Defining an ENV variable with a dynamic value

Tags: docker, dynamic, environment-variables

I want to update the PATH environment variable with a dynamic value. This is what I've tried so far in my Dockerfile:

```
...
ENV PATH '$(dirname $(find /opt -name "ruby" | grep -i bin)):$PATH'
...
```

But export shows that the command was not interpreted:

```
root@97287b22c251:/# export
declare -x PATH="\$(dirname \$(find /opt -name \"ruby\" | grep -i bin)):\$PATH"
```

I don't want to hardcode the value. Is it possible to achieve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

we can't do that, as that would be a huge security issue. Meaning you could run and environment variable  like this

```
 ENV PATH $(rm -rf /)
```

However, you can pass the information through a `--build-arg` (ARG) when building an image;

```
ARG DYNAMIC_VALUE 
ENV PATH=${DYNAMIC_VALUE:-unknown}
RUN echo $PATH
```

and build an image with:

```
> docker build --build-arg DYNAMIC_VALUE=$(dirname $(find /opt -name "ruby" | grep -i bin)):$PATH .
```

Or, if you want to copy information from an existing env-var on the host;

```
> export DYNAMIC_VALUE=foobar
> docker build --build-arg DYNAMIC_VALUE .
```

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if something like this is what you are looking for... slightly modified what you have already. My main question would be, what are you attempting to accomplish with this portion?:
`'$(dirname $(find /opt -name "ruby" | grep -i bin)):$PATH'`
Part of the problem could be usage of single and double quotes resulting in expansions.

```
FROM alpine:3.4
RUN PATH_TO_ADD=$(dirname $(find /opt -name "ruby" | grep -i bin)) || echo Error locating files
ENV PATH "$PATH:$PATH_TO_ADD"
```

Comment: This will not work with docker. More discussion in https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/29110 .