# Statement IF with command in docker file not working

Tags: docker, dockerfile

In my Dockerfile, I have an if statement where I want to check the machine architecture and set this new argument, which I will later use to download the correct file. Even better would be to set the new argument outside of the RUN command, but I don't think that's possible.

```
ARG MACHINE_ARCH=$(uname -m) 
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-o", "pipefail", "-c"] 
RUN \     
    apt-get update && \     
    \     
    if [ "$MACH_ARCH" = "aarch64" ]; then TARGET_ARCH="arm64"; \     
    \     
    elif [ "$MACH_ARCH" = "x86_64" ]; then TARGET_ARCH="amd64"; fi && \
    ...
```

If I dirrectly replace `"$MACH_ARCH"` with `$(uname -m)` in `RUN` command then it works:

```
RUN \
    apt-get update && \
    \
    if [ "$(uname -m)" = "aarch64" ]; then TARGET_ARCH="arm64"; \
    ...
```

Other solution is directly in `RUN` command add argument `BUILD_ARCH`, something like this:

```
RUN \
    apt-get update && \
    \
    BUILD_ARCH=$(uname -m) && \
    \
    if [ "$BUILD_ARCH" = "aarch64" ]; then TARGET_ARCH="arm64"; \
    ...
```

But I would like to have if statement outside of the RUN command, or at least as I have in the first example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker never runs a shell, except in the shell form of `RUN`, `ENTRYPOINT`, and `CMD`.  This means that you're setting the default value of `$MACHINE_ARCH` to the literal string `$(uname -m)`, not the result of running that shell command.

In general, you can't set an environment variable or default build argument value to the result of a shell command.  Also see [Dockerfile - Defining an ENV variable with a dynamic value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34859987/dockerfile-defining-an-env-variable-with-a-dynamic-value).  In this case I might just embed the `$(uname -m)` substitution; maybe in combination with a shell `case` statement; maybe in a script and not directly in the Dockerfile.

In this particular case, though, Docker provides a set of [predefined `ARG`s](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#automatic-platform-args-in-the-global-scope) that identify the build and target architectures.  So long as you're using one of these names, you don't need the `uname` call.  The documentation suggests this is a short name like `arm` or `amd64` so depending on what exactly you're doing you might not even need to remap it to a different value.

```bash
ARG TARGETARCH  # value provided by Docker BuildKit
ARG SOMETHING_VERSION=1.2.3
RUN curl http://download.example.com/something-$SOMETHING_VERSION/something-$TARGETARCH-$SOMETHING_VERSION.tar.gz
```