# On computing a value for an image's $PATH at build-time

Tags: docker, dockerfile, environment-variables

By company policy, whenever we build a Docker image for production, we must follow a procedure that results in the installation of various directory trees under, let's call it, `/companydir`.

Now, the exact set of these directory trees is a function of various parameters that get set only at build-time.  In almost all cases, however, these directory trees include at least one `**/bin` subdirectory containing executable files.

I would like to add all the directories that would get printed by `find /companydir -type d -name bin` to the image's `PATH` variable.  I would like to find a way to do this that is not too contrary to what may be regarded as "best-practice" in such situations.

Unfortunately, the only solutions I can come up with involve injecting code into some startup script (e.g. `/root/.bash_profile`), at build-time.  E.g. by including something like this in the Dockerfile:

```
#syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.4
# ...

RUN <<EOF
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for BINDIR in $( find /companydir -type d -name bin ); do
    if [[ ":$PATH:" != *:$BINDIR:* ]]; then
        PATH=$BINDIR:$PATH
    fi
done

printf -- '\n\nexport PATH=%q\n' "$PATH" >> /root/.bash_profile
EOF

# ...
```

*Ugh*...

Over the years, I have seen this sort of blind modification of startup files lead to a lot of grief, so I am reflexively averse to it.

My preference would be to compute the value of `PATH` at build-time, and use this value in an `ENV PATH=...` statement in the Dockerfile, but AFAICT, the kind of computation I have in mind here is one that Dockerfiles do not support.

Since I am sure that I am not the first to want to compute the value of an `ENV` variable by running a shell command at build-time, my hope is that there a standard solution to this sort of problem.

Comment: While we're talking best practices; note that `for anything in $(find ...)` is an antipattern (in the immediate case, it'll behave badly with files containing spaces); see [BashPitfalls #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

Comment: `printf 'export PATH=%q\n' "$PATH"` is also a safer way to generate an assignment to assign to dotfiles -- that way a directory named `/companydir/$(rm -rf ~)/bin` won't cause the user's shell to delete their home directory during login.

Comment: ...but _in general_, there are already preexisting tools that do this kind of "install each package in its own directory and generate a compound path that includes the subset of tools actively desired". When you choose to roll your solution instead of using preexisting tools, you're responsible for maintenance/etc.

Comment: Among those preexisting tools are -- as something older -- [GNU Stow](https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/), and -- as something much more modern -- [Nix](https://nixos.org/); folks building images using Nix can also use [dockerTools](https://nixos.org/manual/nixpkgs/stable/#sec-pkgs-dockerTools) instead of a Dockerfile at all, making this question moot for them, as the same packages that provide dockerTools also have facilities for assembling a PATH with whichever set of packages is desired in a given context.

Comment: [Dockerfile - Defining an ENV variable with a dynamic value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34859987/dockerfile-defining-an-env-variable-with-a-dynamic-value) seems similar (and no, it's not possible).  Since a Docker image has a fixed filesystem layout that's defined in the Dockerfile, you would typically know exactly which `bin` directories exist.