# How can I evaluate and assign default value to ARG in dockerfile?

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

Basically I want to assign a dynamically calculated default value for `ARG` in my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:20-alpine

ARG RELEASE_TAG=$(git describe --tags --always)

# Other commands...
```

So, far it doesn't interpolate the value of `$(git describe --tags --always)` and simply assigns this value to the `RELEASE_TAG` variable.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: This is similar to [Dockerfile - Defining an ENV variable with a dynamic value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34859987/dockerfile-defining-an-env-variable-with-a-dynamic-value).  The same rules apply to `ARG` and `ENV`: Docker does no substitutions here other than simple variable substitution, and it in particular does not run subcommands here.

Comment: Are there any pariticular reasons you want to do this instead of doing it on the `docker build` command line ?

Comment: @Philippe I do not have control over `docker build` as it is managed via organization wide remote GitHub Action script. So, I need to handle this inside the Dockerfile itself.

Comment: @DavidMaze, if that's the case, it looks like I will always have to call this command at each step separately if `ARG` doesn't support substitutions.

Comment: Can you show how `RELEASE_TAG` gets used ?

Comment: @philippe, like this: `RUN npm run build -- --version=$RELEASE_TAG` and `RUN npm run upload-sourcemaps -- --version=$RELEASE_TAG`. And, then one more command at the bottom that uses same **variable**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the expected effect by putting it in RUN :

```
FROM ubuntu

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git
RUN RELEASE_TAG=$(git describe --tags --always) &&\
    echo npm run build -- --version=$RELEASE_TAG

CMD sleep inf
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `--build-arg` argument with `docker build`

```
export RELEASE_TAG=$(git describe --tags --always)
docker build --build-arg RELEASE_TAG=$RELEASE_TAG -t your_image_name .
```

And inside your Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:20-alpine

ARG RELEASE_TAG
```

That way, RELEASE_TAG will now have the value of `git describe --tags --always` output.

Comment: Don't forget the quotes

Comment: I don't want to pass this info via `docker build` command as I do not have control over how `docker build` is invoked. That's why I am seeking the way to do this inside the Dockerfile itself.