# How to calculate and set PATH inside Dockerfile, once and forever?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

This is my `Dockerfile` (I need to generate the path in runtime, I don't know it upfront):

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04
RUN year=$(date +%Y) \
  && echo "export PATH=\${PATH}:/usr/local/${year}" >> /root/.bashrc
```

Then, I build the image and run a container:

```
$ docker build . -t tmp
$ docker run --rm tmp env
```

The `PATH` doesn't include `/usr/local/2024`.

AFAIU, it's not possible to use `ENV` for this, since the `PATH` is not static, but generated when the image is being built.

Comment: You've asked two previous questions on this, which have both been closed as duplicates; how is this one different?  Especially [Dockerfile - Defining an ENV variable with a dynamic value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34859987/dockerfile-defining-an-env-variable-with-a-dynamic-value) seems to ask pretty much exactly the same question you're asking here.

Comment: You fully control the container filesystem, so you should be able to use a fixed path, maybe as a symlink to the desired path, or maybe just `COPY`ing the dynamic-path host content to a fixed path in the image.

Comment: When I install [TeXLive](https://www.tug.org/texlive/), it installs into a directory with a year inside (pretty much like the example above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run a non-interactive shell, bash doesn't read your `.bashrc` file. Compare:

```
$ docker run --rm pathtest env | grep PATH
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

With:

```
$ docker run -it --rm pathtest
root@6e9bfd8a4e04:/# env | grep PATH
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/2024
```

Note that in the second case, in which we start an interactive shell, `PATH` includes `/usr/local/2024`.

---

I think the best way of handling this would be to set `PATH` in an [`ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/dockerfile/#entrypoint) script. E.g.:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "export PATH=\"${PATH}:/usr/local/$(date +%Y)\" && exec \"$@\"", "--"]
CMD ["bash"]
```

This will set `PATH` regardless of what you pass as the command, so your test now works as expected:

```
$ docker run --rm pathtest env | grep PATH
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/2024
```